# Execute Node.JS script via crontab on OS X

Tags: node.js, cron

I have been trying to figure out how to use crontabs on my mac OS X I have a node script written that I would like to be able to execute in a scheduled manner.  Here is the line I am using in my crontab file.

```
30 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /Users/pmanca/Google Drive/JavaScript/code/Peter/marketing-tests/testBackup.js
```

It doesn't appear to be executing though.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Also is there another way on a mac or linux server to accomplish what I'm looking for?  Also can you use the same line for a crontab job in linux as well(besides the file paths needing to change)?

Comment: Try escaping the space: `30 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /Users/pmanca/Google\ Drive/JavaScript/code/Peter/marketing-tests/testBackup.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the two npm packages, [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) or [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda)

Both work on linux and OS X. Cron is best if your tasks are lightweight and you don't need your jobs to be persisted into db. Agenda uses mongodb for persistence.

You can configure a job in cron as:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime:  '00 */30 * * * *',
  onTick: function() {
    /*
     * Runs every 30 minutes, every hour, every day, all week
     */
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
job.start();
```

To run in background on server you can run it with [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Remember cron has an additional 6th place to the left for seconds. Otherwise the syntax is same.

Comment: Oh this is awesome.  The task I want to run is backing up a database in MongoDB.  Do you still think cron is the right way?  What do you mean by Agenda uses mongodb for persistence.

Comment: Agenda stores the jobs you define into a mongo collection (agendaJobs I guess) and runs the jobs according to the values stored in it.

Cron on the other hand uses system time for the jobs defined as part of the script to run.

Comment: I personally had a bad experience with agenda due to it's dependency on db, and difficulty in setting a timezone related jobs. I have used cron at least on two production instances, one of which required Los Angeles timezone. Working smoothly without a glitch.

Comment: Since I will be already running a mongo server do you think there is any benefit in going that way?  Not sure If I really need the job to live in a db or not

Comment: ok cool thanks for the personal experience. I'll try it using cron now

Comment: If you don't have a timezone constraint you can use agenda equally well. I don't recommend against it. Just shared personal experience.

Comment: This works, I'm trying to figure out the cron time.  I tried '*/00 */5 * * * *' and it seemed to wait a couple minutes and then it just fired off every second after that.  Can you expand upon how the timing works?  The goal was to test it out running every 5 minutes

Comment: Use 00 */5 * * * * for 5 minutes. 00 means run at 0th second.

Comment: so what is the real difference between 00 and */00 then?

Answer (score 0):

By default `cron` process doesn't have the required permission to access the disk in macos. So, you should allow full access disk to `cron` process. For this one, add `/usr/sbin/cron` to your allowed full disk access process under Security & Privacy. Further information can be seen in [How to Fix Cron Permission Issues in MacOS Catalina & Mojave](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/)